# Emscripten: how to increase heap memory from 16 MB

Tags: emscripten

Why I am unable to pre-load any .data of size more than **10** MB on chrome/edge/Firefox
I used  set_target_properties(test.js PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "--preload-file ../folder")
folder's size is > 10 MB. The folder had dat files but It doenst even work with png even with --use-preload-plugins

Envrionment: emscripten 1.39.16/Linux(wsl 20.04)

```
test.js:1 Uncaught RangeError: offset is out of bounds
    at Uint8Array.set (<anonymous>)
    at processPackageData (test.js:1)
    at test.js:1
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (test.js:1)
```

Alternative approach with  file_packager.py model.data --preload ../folder --js-output=model.js
Later added few runtime functions FS_createPath, addRunDependency, getMemory but got same error.

```
var ptr = Module['getMemory'](byteArray.length);
         Module['HEAPU8'].set(byteArray, ptr);
```

`file_packager.py`has conditions  for size greater than 256 MB which I  do receive if I package 250+MB directory

```
 # TODO: sha256sum on data_target
    if start > 256 * 1024 * 1024:
      print('warning: file packager is creating an asset bundle of %d MB. '
            'this is very large, and browsers might have trouble loading it. '
            'see https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/02/synchronous-execution-and-filesystem-access-in-emscripten/'
            % (start / (1024 * 1024)), file=sys.stderr)
```

Packaging works for all types of sizes

> warning: file packager is creating an asset bundle of 468 MB. this is very large, and browsers might have trouble loading it.

```
set(EMSCRIPTEN_LINK_FLAGS "${EMSCRIPTEN_LINK_FLAGS} --use-preload-plugins -s WASM=1 -s TOTAL_MEMORY=1024MB")
```

-> Not working

Answer (score 0):

default heap memory of wasm is 16 MB.

I was using wrong cmake options.

Correct option for 1GB memory :

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-s TOTAL_MEMORY=1024MB")
```